# How to get access to MusicTracks in a MusicSequence?

Tags: iphone, c, ios, xcode, audio

So, I'm trying to figure out the MusicPlayer API for iOS. I have been able to get a MIDI to play, so my sequence is there and populated with something useful but I can't seem to get access to the tracks (or in this case track, as there is only one music track, the other is a tempo track).

If I run a MusicSequenceGetTrackCount on "mySequence" I get a return of 2; this is expected.

If I run a MusicSequenceGetInfoDictionary, it returns 3 entries:

```
Printing description of sequenceInfo:
{
    tempo = 120;
    "time signature" = "4/4";
    title = "RHand";
}
```

This makes sense since all of this info matches up with my track.

So, all of this would make me think if I use the method MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(MusicSequence inSequence, UInt32 inTrackIndex, MusicTrack *outTrack) I should be able to output the track so I can make some modification.

Here's my code so far. If anyone could take a look and see where I'm going wrong, that'd be great. Also, if anyone has some good resources about using MusicPlayer, I'd be really grateful. Thanks.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/MusicPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *noteDisplayLabel;
@property MusicSequence mySequence;
@property MusicPlayer player;
@property MusicEventIterator iterator;
@property MusicTrack RHand;
@property MusicTrack LHand;


- (IBAction)practiceLesson:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)changeTempo:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize noteDisplayLabel, mySequence, player, iterator, RHand, LHand;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CFBundleRef appBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFStringRef filename = CFSTR("simpleCScale");
    CFStringRef ext = CFSTR("mid");

    CFURLRef fileLocation = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(appBundle, filename, ext, NULL);

    NewMusicSequence(&mySequence);

    MusicSequenceFileLoad(mySequence, fileLocation, 0, kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks);

    NewMusicPlayer(&player);

    UInt32 trackCount;
    MusicSequenceGetTrackCount(mySequence, &trackCount);

    NSLog(@"Number of tracks: %lu", trackCount);

    CFDictionaryRef sequenceInfo;
    sequenceInfo = MusicSequenceGetInfoDictionary(mySequence);

    UInt32 trackIndex = 0;
    MusicTrack track;
    MusicSequenceGetIndTrack (mySequence,trackIndex,&track);

    MusicEventIterator iter;
    Boolean hasEvent = 0;
    NewMusicEventIterator(track, &iter);

    Boolean hasNextEvent = 1;

    while (hasNextEvent == 1) {
        MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iter, &hasEvent);
        NSLog(@"Has Event: %i", hasEvent);

        MusicTimeStamp timestamp;
        MusicEventType eventType = 0;
        void *eventData = NULL;
        UInt32 eventDataSize;

        MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iter, &timestamp, &eventType, eventData, &eventDataSize);
        NSLog(@"Event %f: Type = %lu, Data = %p, Size = %lu", timestamp, eventType, eventData, eventDataSize);

        MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(iter);
        MusicEventIteratorHasNextEvent(iter, &hasNextEvent);
        NSLog(@"More Events? : %i", hasNextEvent);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setNoteDisplayLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)practiceLesson:(id)sender {
    MusicPlayerSetSequence(player, mySequence);
    MusicPlayerStart(player);
}

- (IBAction)changeTempo:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

***EDIT***

Tried doing the following in the viewDidLoad method but it didn't work:

```
UInt32 trackIndex = 1;
MusicTrack *track;
MusicSequenceGetIndTrack (mySequence,trackIndex,&track);
```

***EDIT***

Updated the above code to include changes. I have the eventIterator working now but I can't seem to get any event data out of it? Running the program gives me the following output:

```
2012-03-13 14:09:39.709 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Number of tracks: 2
2012-03-13 14:09:39.711 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.712 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 0.000000: Type = 7, Data = 0x0, Size = 4
2012-03-13 14:09:39.713 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.714 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.714 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 0.000000: Type = 7, Data = 0x0, Size = 4
2012-03-13 14:09:39.715 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.716 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.716 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 0.000000: Type = 7, Data = 0x0, Size = 4
2012-03-13 14:09:39.717 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.718 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.719 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 0.000000: Type = 7, Data = 0x0, Size = 4
2012-03-13 14:09:39.719 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.720 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.845 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 0.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.846 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.846 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.847 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 1.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.847 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.848 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.849 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 2.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.850 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.850 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.851 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 3.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.851 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.852 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.853 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 4.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.887 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.888 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.888 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 5.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.889 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.890 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.891 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 6.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.891 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.892 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.893 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 7.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.893 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.894 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.895 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 8.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.899 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.900 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.901 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 9.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.902 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.902 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.903 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 10.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.904 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.905 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.905 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 11.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.906 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.907 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.908 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 12.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.908 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.909 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.928 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 13.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.929 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.930 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.930 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 14.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.931 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.932 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.932 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 15.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.933 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.933 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Has Event: 1
2012-03-13 14:09:39.934 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] Event 16.000000: Type = 6, Data = 0x0, Size = 8
2012-03-13 14:09:39.935 musicPlayerSandbox[61775:f803] More Events? : 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access any track you will first need to access musicSequence. In your case you have `mySequence`
for this also you know the total number of tracks in music sequence as `trackCount`. Now to access particular track you will simply need to use

```
MusicTrack *track;
MusicSequenceGetIndTrack (mySequence,trackIndex,&track);
```

This will give you track. Also, make sure that `trackIndex < trackCount`.

**Update**

As per [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicTrack_Reference/Reference/reference.html).

The music track and related opaque types are declared in the `MusicPlayer.h` header file.

So you will need to use (MusicTrack is opaque type not a class.)

```
MusicTrack track; //without star sign. rest remains the same.
```

**Update for EventIterator**

As you said MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo() method takes parameter `const void **outEventData` for event data therefore you will need to pass it as `&outEventData` and not the `outEventData` only.

So in your code change following line:

```
MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iter, &timestamp, &eventType, &eventData, &eventDataSize);
```

Comment: Hey. I tried this out and it gave me an warning: "Incompatible pointer types passing 'MusicTrack **' (aka 'struct OpaqueMusicTrack ***') to parameter of type 'MusicTrack *' (aka 'struct OpaqueMusicTrack **')remove &". So I tried removing the & from before track but this gives me another warning: Variable 'track' is uninitialized when used here. So, when I set track to NULL to begin with, it doesn't give any warnings but it also doesn't work :(

Comment: Hey, that worked great thanks :) I'm trying to get the eventData out of the events but I can't seem to figure out how to format my eventData variable. I've added the code changes to the question. The reference says that the eventData type is "const void **outEventData" but I'm not sure what that means. From what I can tell, you would need a void pointer pointer?